# Scope doesn't receive array as argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have the following scope defined in my model:

```
  scope :answers_in, -> (answers = nil) do
    return unless answers.present?
    where(answer_1: answers).or(where(answer_2: answers))
  end
```

The `answers` should by an array. However, when I make a call passing an array, receive an argument error:

```
AnswerConnection.answers_in([1, 2])
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
        from /vagrant/farma_alg_reborn/app/models/answer_connection.rb:7:in `block in <class:AnswerConnection>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:159:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in scope'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:351:in `scoping'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:159:in `block in scope'
        from (irb):2
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /vagrant/farma_alg_reborn/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Is this a bug, Rails scopes doesn't work with arrays or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put an argument into the `or` method. Try this:

```
where(user_1: answers).or(where(user_2: answers))
```

---

**UPDATE** (ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments)

You can't set a default parameter value for scopes:

```
scope :answers_in, -> (answers = nil) do
```

So, replace it with:

```
scope :answers_in, -> (answers) do
```

Or if you want the argument to be optional, define the scope like this:

```
scope :answers_in, -> (*answers) do
```

But then you have to pass array elements as separated arguments `AnswerConnection.answers_in(1, 2)` instead of `AnswerConnection.answers_in([1, 2])`.

Comment: I update my answer to this (and changed `user_x` to `answer_x`, I accidendally switched). That returns me an argument error again.

Comment: Which is the seventh line in your AnswerConnection model? (reffering to `from /vagrant/farma_alg_reborn/app/models/answer_connection.rb:7:in block in <class:AnswerConnection>'`)

Comment: It's the scope declaration: `scope :answers_in, -> (answers = nil) do`

Comment: So, are you sure, you're passing just an answers array into this method? The error says, you're trying to put two arguments into it. Could you show me, how are you calling this scope?

Comment: Yes, I passed a simple array, just to test: `AnswerConnection.answers_in([1, 2])`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Only a correction: `scope :answers_in, -> (*answers) do` works informing an array as parameter: `AnswerConnection.answers_in([1, 2])`. Here is the resulting query of this example: `SELECT "answer_connections".* FROM "answer_connections" WHERE ("answer_connections"."answer_1_id" IN (1, 2) OR "answer_connections"."answer_2_id" IN (1, 2))`